# IE7 Text in DIV without line causes div to stretch too far

Tags: text, html, internet-explorer-7, width

These are two of the pages in question I have issues with viewed in IE7 or in IE8 in compatibility mode.

http://ancientadornment.com/medievalbeads.aspx

http://ancientadornment.com/egyptianbeads.aspx

These pages have text without line breaks in them, and it's causing the DIV to stretch out to the length of the page instead of the 100% I have specified. Any idea why this is happening? It looks good in IE8, IE9, and Firefox, but I cannot seem to get this to work. I put it in a DIV of 100%, and it still does it. I have tried to set a maximum width, but that has no effect.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IE (especially 7) tends to have a lot of issues like this one. It may be better to try and work with IE7 separately by over-riding all of the issues in a separate css file. To make a seperate css file do this:

```
<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="YourFile.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"/><![endif]-->
```

I have always found that editing the css in my default css file to fix IE 7 issues will always cause more issues in other browsers

Comment: I know about this, it's just, I need to know what the issue is that's causing this to happen.